# Writing to a CSV file: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, file, csv, beautifulsoup

The code scrapes an individual event from the card but I keep getting this error:

> C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/James/PycharmProjects/scraperscrappy
>   /scrapy.py   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:/Users/James/PycharmProjects/scraperscrappy/scrapy.py", line  31, in 
>         writer.writerow(c)    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

I am using pyCharm.

Process finished with exit code 1
Python creates the csv file on the fly,but I also tried creating a csv file within the project but I still got the same message.I think the problem may lie in the strings after the zip in line 31.Any help appreciated.

```
import csv
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?id=1793467")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

one = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "first essential fin"})
two = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "essential greyhound"})

three = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "timeDistance"})
four = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
five = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "sp"})
six = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "timeSec"})
seven = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "essential trainer"})
eight = bsObj.findAll("li", {"class": "first essential comment"})

firstessentialfin = [a.getText().strip() for a in one]
essentialgreyhound = [b.getText().strip() for b in two]
timeDistance = [c.getText().strip() for c in three]
trap = [d.getText().strip() for d in four]
sp = [e.getText().strip() for e in five]
timeSec = [f.getText().strip() for f in six]
essentialtrainer = [g.getText().strip() for g in seven]
firstessentialcomment = [h.getText().strip() for h in eight]

with open('dogfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
for c in zip(firstessentialfin, essentialgreyhound, timeDistance,    trap,sp, timeSec, essentialtrainer,
         firstessentialcomment):
    writer.writerow(c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the indentation. Move the for loop to under the `with` context manager body:

```
with open('dogfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for c in zip(firstessentialfin, essentialgreyhound, timeDistance,    trap,sp, timeSec, essentialtrainer, firstessentialcomment):
        writer.writerow(c)
```

Comment: hi alecxe.Thaks for that it works perfect.I had used ctrl alt and L to indent but this doesn't always work.Many thanks for that.